# Concatenation with dynamic variables for Twig symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a specific problem with concat of twig. 
When I trying to concatenate dynamic variables showing the error.
Here is my code :

```
{% set i = 0 %}
{% set nbLignes = codeEvt.nb_lignes_~i %}
{% set nbLignesRef = codeEvt.nb_lignes_ref_~i %}
```

But I have this error message :

> Method "nb_lignes_" for object "\DTO\SuiviJourFonc" does not exist in XXXXXXXXX.html.twig at line 211

I would like to take **codeEvt.nb_lignes_0** , but i would like build a "for" for others variables like `nb_lignes_1, nb_lignes_2 , nb_lignes_3 ...`

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`attribute` can be used to access a *`dynamic`* attribute of a variable:
The attribute function was added in Twig 1.2.

```
{{ attribute(object, method) }}

{{ attribute(object, method,arguments) }}

{{ attribute(array, item) }}
```

Try like this,

```
{{ attribute(codeEvt, 'nb_lignes_ref_' ~ i) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the array-like notation:

```
{{ codeEvt['nb_lignes_ref_' ~ i] }}
```

Or even use string interpolation:

```
{{ codeEvt["nb_lignes_ref_#{i}"] }}
```